# Safari Mobile - what does site need?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

What special meta tags, CSS, etc. do I need to take into consideration when making my website ready to look and function right in Safari Mobile.

I didn't take much consideration to Safari Mobile until I got an iPad. I noticed that the sites I create do not always re-size correctly, look well formatted, etc. Nothing major as I am largely a front end developer.

I searched through StackOverflow and have not found a real specific outline of Safari-Mobile considerations

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your site is already designed in a fluid manner.  One of the big things for me was this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

This sets the size of the viewport so when orientation changes it resizes the viewport which allows your design to reflow to the new viewport size.

Comment: Rather than fixed widths/heights, they should be auto?

Comment: Auto or percentage based.  You can control the range they scale with min/max width so that you can define at which point they stop scaling up or down

Comment: anytime <some filler text to get above limit>